# How to determine if row already exists on an Insert

Tags: postgresql, go

My goal is to determine if the error was because the record already exists according to our database indexing which ensures uniqueness:

[image]

the problem is that I don't see an error that corresponds to a record already existing. Do I really have to read the db first to see if it exists?

I googled for:

> unique constraint violation error postgres golang

I see something like this on a reddit thread lol

```
if pgerr, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
    if pgerr.Code == "23505" {
        //handle duplicate insert
    }
}
```

That seems like it could work but I am looking for a best practice here..

Comment: If you're using `lib/pq` then [`err.(*pq.Error)`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error) is the correct approach to get more details on the error.

Comment: Which database library are you using?

Comment: postgres is the db I am using thx

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman What do you want to do if row already exists? An update on the row?

Comment: If you want to do an update if it exists and otherwise an insert, you're looking for an Upsert (Update/Insert) depending which database you use you can write a query for that.

Comment: yeah in this case I don't want to upsert, just figure out what kind of error there was in the insert